# c++ Cannot find -l-static-libgcc

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors

When I'm compiling a binary file I keep getting the following errors even though I have the dependencies.

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l-static-libgcc

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l-static-libstdc++

Comment: Most library names don't start with a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop the `-l` and just write `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++`.  Those GCC options are documented here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

If you write `-l-static-libgcc`, the compiler will naively look for a library named `lib-static-libgcc.a`, and it will still link in the default runtime libraries.